# Facebook Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a desktop javascript application, and I am getting this error message when trying to access it from my ipad, it works fine when accessing from desktop and on my android phone. I am logged into facebook on my devices.

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

My settings are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Why doesnt it work on ios?